# The "value" field doesn't exist on the "RFPDateJSONParser$ReturnedRecord" object, or you don't have access to the field

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I have an apex class created and tested that parses a JSON string. This is not a complete sample, just showing the relevent return class called ReturnedRecord

```
public with sharing class RFPDateJSONParser {

public class RFPDateJSONParserRequest {
    @InvocableVariable
    public String jsonString;
}

public class RFPDateJSONParserResponse {
    @InvocableVariable
    public List<ReturnedRecord> parsedData;
}

public class ReturnedRecord {
    @InvocableVariable
    public String type;
    @InvocableVariable
    public String value;
    @InvocableVariable
    public String year;
}
```

When I tried to access this in a loop, I get the following error saying I don't have access to the property or it doesn't exist. Stumped.
[image: Flow Screen Shot]

Comment: How did you set up `Date_Records_Loop` in your flow? This is the kind of error that I'd expect to see if you're trying to access a variable on a list instead of accessing it on individual items in a list. I.e. The assignment should be inside/part of a loop element.

Comment: @DerekF I setup the loop calling the Date_Records_Loop and in the bottom it says "To use the current item in other elements in the loop, use the API name of the Loop element. Example: if your flow iterates over accounts with a Loop element named "My_Account_Loop" you can reference the current item from that loop element. Just start typing "My_Account_Loop" and select "Current Item from Loop My_Account_Loop". 

This indicates to use the name of the Loop which is what I've done and the error is referencing the right return type.